# 0 - Input_0:112: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode

Tags: arguments

I am stumped!

Getting the error, then refresh page it disappears. I really hope someone can point me  in the right directions. NO IDEA what is causing it... Using apache, nginx, Joomla,...

> 0 - Input_0:112: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode

---

> 0 - Input_0:112: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode if(arguments.callee && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:113: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:114: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller.toString().indexOf('isPropagationStopped') !== -1){  //jquery mark ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:122: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode if(arguments.callee && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:123: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:124: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller.toString().indexOf('isPropagationStopped') !== -1){    //jquery mark ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:132: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode if(arguments.callee && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:133: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller && ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Input_0:134: ERROR - "arguments.callee" cannot be used in strict mode arguments.callee.caller.toString().indexOf('isPropagationStopped') !== -1){    //jquery mark ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

For me this was a issue with the T3 Framework in /plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/js/script.js

I have commented out lines 102 - 142 which are using the depreciated `arguments.callee` method.

Hope this helps.

Craig

Comment: You bet that helps Craig! I Could not find information about it anywhere. Can you see any negative effect of commenting out those lines?

Comment: @Colin I think the offending code is some sort of compatibility checker for MooTools. So as long as your not using that it should be okay. I haven't had any negative effects as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I followed the instructions above, but had no luck initially.
What worked for me was to comment out the offending function in the file script.js, but under a neighbouring directory, namely
plugins/system/t3/base/js/script.js
I hope this helps someone.
Thanks for the initial pointers!

Answer (score 0):

1. File: `\plugins\system\t3\base-bs3\js\menu.js`
2. Line: 15
3. Remove char ";" (alone char before main code)